# Blank applet layout coming in Siebel before OpenUI rendering happens

Tags: siebel

We are using Siebel citizen portal application (IP 15.12). After login, we reach in to a landing page with 3 applets. These applets have some custom fields etc, but there is no UI customization we did (ie no PM/PR etc).

Now when we login, a blank layout of the applet appears for a few seconds (especially first load or after clearing cache) and then renders the original applet with Open UI layout. Since this is a customer facing application, our client has a lot of concern on appearing the blank layout before the actual rendered applet.

Could anyone throw some light here? Is this an Open UI behavior, if so is there any workaround for this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

With IP 15.18, We had similar issue of the list applets not loading data on initial (home page load) after login. Only the list applet titles were displayed but the form applet loaded elements, showing the busy cursor forever...

We were getting "Error downloading file define:siebel/htmltmplmgr" error in the browser console. we debugged and found that the localeobject.js was not loading, which is the dependency file mentioned in htmltmplmgr.js...So we added preload define parameter in the htmltmplmgr.js in the beginning to load the localeobject.js file before even the main function starts...then it started working...try this...

Answer (score 0):

On first load or after clear cahce, it needs to load all JS files (vanilla) and other required files in Open UI. So, this is the default behavior of OpenUI.

Nothing much we can do with this. Else you can tweak down all unnecessary files from downloading.
I found this blog very useful, you can check.

http://www.askmesiebel.com/category/siebel-8-1-1-10-upgrade-issue/

Answer (score 0):

edit the file htmltmplmgr.js in below folders

$SIEBEL_ROOT/siebsrvr/webmaster/siebel_build/scripts/siebel/ 
$SIEBEL_ROOT/SWEApp/public/enu/23048/scripts/siebel/
go to define section and add dependency files inside the square brackets
define("siebel/htmltmplmgr",[]

`define("siebel/htmltmplmgr",["siebel/siebelconstants.js","siebel/localeobject.js"]`

Note that you have to edit the files in both folders you can create a backup before making changes. If you just replace in public folder when you restart siebel server files will be overwritten from webmaster/siebel_build folder to public folder . Hence you have to replace in both folders and restart siebel server and web server.